# Maven offline: Plugin not found error

Tags: java, maven

I got below compile error in my pom.xml. I want to work with my pom.xml in offline mode. I have dependencies in my repositry. Do I need to install a jar or pom.xml in the org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin?. I tried to insert a jar of maven-javadoc-plugin, but it failed. Please help me with this error Or give me some information, I don't know how to solve it. Below is my pom.xml. I know that I have to do something in my .m2 directory.

Please find below error:

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users
 \myname\.m2\repository), nexus-chrono (http://192.168.241.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/)]: Plugin not found in any 
 plugin repository

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


    <parent>
        <groupId>es.chx</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>es.chx.gestionEnvios</groupId>

    <artifactId>gestionEnvios</artifactId>
    <name>gestionEnvios</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.springframework-version>2.5</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>es.chx</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-chx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>es.chx.web</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>loginLiferayFromApp</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>es.chx.web</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>commonWeb</artifactId>  -->
<!--            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!-- -->        <dependency> 
<!-- -->            <groupId>es.chx.intranet</groupId> 
<!--  -->           <artifactId>commonIntranet</artifactId>
<!-- -->            <version>1.0</version> 
<!-- -->        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag-doc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag-export-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajaxtags</groupId>
            <artifactId>ajaxtags</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-beta-rc7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib-ext-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>es.chx.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>nexus-chrono</id>
            <url>http://192.168.241.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration></configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The maven is unable to find the plugins in any of the repository you mentioned in pom.xml. Do you have internet connection and what is your settings.xml?

Comment: mvn unable to find the repository from given URL

nexus-chrono (http://192.168.241.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/)]: Plugin not found in any 
 plugin repository

Answer (score 1):

In your m2 repository at `C:\Users\myname\.m2\repository`, you need both

- the application dependencies
- **and** the maven plugins used in your POM, `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin` in that particular case

Comment: yo mean something like this:  <project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </reporting>
  ...
</project> To edit a new dependency in my pom.xml with the plugin? I tried before but im not sure i this will work. thx for your advice

Comment: Yes. Those plugins are jars, which are (build) dependencies for your project. Maven needs them to work offline. You can download them from your nexus repository when you have access to it. The easier is to run `mvn package` on your local machine when you have access to Nexus. Unless you have a specific configuration, this will also download the plugins to you repository

Comment: I think that i dont have enoughts rights to access nexus, but maybe the solution could be that, add the dependency in pom.xml (maven compiler). Download it, and maybe the errors in pom.xml would dissapear. However, thanks for your answers Bruno Grieder.

Comment: Sure. You can download the jar and put it in `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/2.10.3/`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work in offline mode. Please make sure below things.

- Did you install required maven-javadoc-plugin locally using the

  mvn install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion=  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
- Check the settings.xml whether possibility to work offline mode

  false